# intergrating xcode to mopub

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I keep getting an error trying to integrate mopub to iOS. It keeps giving me server response indicated no ad is available.

```
 MPAdView *adView = [[MPAdView alloc] initWithAdUnitId:@"<xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>"   size:MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE];
adView.delegate = self;

CGRect frame = adView.frame;
CGSize size = [adView adContentViewSize];
frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height - size.height;
adView.frame = frame;

[adView loadAd];
[self.view addSubview:adView];
[adView release];
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, can someone help me out.

Comment: Should there be an ad available? I don't see anything wrong with the code you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Mopub marketplace allocation is 100% for your ad unit.
Sometimes test mode of mopub is not working as well, or there may be connection problem (especially in simulator).

You may use mediation as alternative, use admob or iAd besides marketplace ads (Assuming you implement mopub full bundle).
If you enabled iAds you can test it out in real device, opening developer mode.
You can open up developer mode on real device (iphone or ipad) in settings - Developer with %100 or else fill rate.

Google ads can be set to test ads from admob panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing test mode as indicated here:

https://github.com/mopub/mopub-client/wiki/Testing-Ad-Units

Just make sure that when you submit your app to the app store, remove the test flags.